# В WAMP (openserver) не работает ajax. По какой причине может быть?

Tags: ajax

```
<Html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Ajax полный контроль</title>
   <script type="application/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function funcBefore(){
            $("information").text ("Ожидание данных...");
        }

        function funcSuccess(data){
            $("information").text (data);
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#load").bind("click", function(){
            var admin = "administrator";
               $.ajax ( {
                   url: "content.php",
                   type: "POST",
                   data: ({name: admin, number: 5}),
                   DataType: "html",
                   beforeSend: funcBefore,
                   success: funcSuccess
               });
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>    
    <body>
        <p id="load" style="cursor:pointer">Загрузка данных</p>
        <div id="information"></div>
    </body>
</Html>

<?php
    sleep(2);
    echo "Данные: строка -". $_POST['name'].", цифра- ". $_POST['number'];
?>
```

Comment: Напишите подробнее, в чём заключается проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте подключить jQuery так:
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```js
function funcBefore(){
   $("#information").text ("Ожидание данных...");
}

function funcSuccess(data){
   $("#information").text (data);
}
```

Вы обращались к полю information без #.

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема решена.